# How to format a 3-digit integer to a 4-digit string?

Tags: java

I would like to format a 3-digit `integer` to a 4-digit `string` value. Example:

```
int a = 800;
String b = "0800";
```

Of course the formatting will be done at `String b` statement. Thanks guys!

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use [String#format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String b = String.format("%04d", a);
```

For other formats refer the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: Crap, almost 24hrs and I totally forgot to accept this answer! My bad!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have it only once use `String.format("%04d", number)` - if you need it more often and want to centralize the pattern (e.g. config file) see the solution below.

Btw. there is an Oracle [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) on number formatting.

To make it short:

```
import java.text.*;

public class Demo {

   static public void main(String[] args) {
      int value = 123;
      String pattern="0000";
      DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
      String output = myFormatter.format(value);
      System.out.println(output); // 0123
   }
}
```

Hope that helps.
*Jost

Comment: This actually, might be somewhat better.

Answer (score 3):

Please try

```
String.format("%04d", b);
```

Comment: Beside `b` instead of `a`, how this answer differs from Thilo's answer?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Well, look at the timestamps. Most likely just a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

```
String b = "0" + a;
```

Could it be easier?

Comment: @SandiipPatil That won't compile.

Comment: Could it be easier? No. But maybe more robust/flexible.

Comment: @Thilo: agreed. But the question specifically asked for 3-digits integers. Why make things complex when they can be simple? Now, I also agree that your solution is far from being complex :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. It should be like this
 'String b = "0"+ Integer.valueOf(a).toString();'

Comment: I think both our solutions may have trouble with negative numbers. Let's leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @SandiipPatil Euh... `"0" + a` works just fine...

Comment: Yeah simplest will be your solution but to intake any value Integer might work

Comment: If negative you should do: `String b = "-0" + a * -1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [Jodd Printf](http://jodd.org/doc/printf.html) for that. In your case:

```
Printf.str("%04d", 800);
```

would do the job. This class was created before Sun added `String.format` and has somewhat more formatting options.